# Calling JavaScript from Obj C - Without a WebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to call a JavaScript function from an Objective-C method without using a web view? What I want to do is to simulate pressing a link (say Add) on a webpage, whenever an NSButton is pressed. I know which JavaScript function is called, whenever 'Add' is pressed.

I don't have a web view in the app and this is not an iPhone app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not an iPhone app.

In this case, you're lucky - you can use the [JavaScriptCore framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/WebKit_JavaScriptCore_Ref/_index.html) for calling JavaScript from C programs.

(For future reference: this framework is also available on iOS, but it's private - you can use it for in-house and jailbroken development, but not in an AppStore app. [Opensource ports](https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS) of Apple's JavaScriptCore exist as well, as pointed out by @JustSid.)

Comment: There are open source ports of JavaScript Core for iOS. Like this one [here](https://github.com/phoboslab/JavaScriptCore-iOS)

Comment: @JustSid Thanks! I'll incorporate that one into my answer.

Comment: @JustSid,H2CO3 - Thank you guyz for the help.